# webdriver API: how to disable verbose error messages?

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver

Running the example source at

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

It runs successfully, however Eclipse throws bunch of WARNING messages. How Can I disable this from displaying ? All I really need is the last line `Page title is: Cheese! - Google Search`

```
17-Aug-2010 12:07:00 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.StringUtils parseHttpDate
WARNING: Unable to parse date: -1
17-Aug-2010 12:07:00 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.StringUtils parseHttpDate
WARNING: Unable to parse date: -1
17-Aug-2010 12:07:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [1:4686] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
17-Aug-2010 12:07:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [1:4686] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
17-Aug-2010 12:07:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [1:6505] Error in expression. Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Page title is: Cheese! - Google Search
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer given by zloiadun didn't work here, instead I had to use,

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger ("");
logger.setLevel (Level.OFF);
```

.. changing the getLogger( .. ) and level as needed.

Answer (score 7):

Though none of these things worked for me, I found that I could shut HTMLUnit up by making a custom errorhandler... this is kinda cheesy... but it gives you excellent control should you need it:

```
        webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
        //Saint
        @Override
        public void warning(CSSParseException arg0) throws CSSException {
            // stare blankly

        }

        @Override
        public void fatalError(CSSParseException arg0) throws CSSException {
            // twiddle thumbs

        }

        @Override
        public void error(CSSParseException arg0) throws CSSException {
            // drool on shirt

        }
    });
```

Comment: This one really helped me. But actually this solution is also available out of the box now: `client.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler())`

Answer (score 4):

As discussed here: [Can't turn off HtmlUnit logging messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188118/cant-turn-off-htmlunit-logging-messages)

The following code worked best for me:

```
static {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but didn't for me.  I had to use James' version instead, with the unnamed logger.

Comment: This works for me. And to totally shut HtmlUnitDriver up, you can just set the level to *java.util.logging.Level.OFF*.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property helps:

**log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler=ERROR**

I did it in **logging.properties** and piece of my build.xml, for instance:

```
<target name="selenium">
    <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <sysproperty key="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties" />
        ...
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit uses the Commons Logging. You can refer [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html) for more details.

As quick hint, you can disable warnings by setting the following system property:

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
```