# Fixing HttpClient warning "Invalid expires attribute" using fluent API

Tags: cookies, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using the fluent API of HttpClient to make a GET request:

```java
String jsonResult = Request.Get(requestUrl)
            .connectTimeout(2000)
            .socketTimeout(2000)
            .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

But for each request I get the following warning:

```
apr 07, 2016 12:26:46 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: WMF-Last-Access=07-Apr-2016;Path=/;HttpOnly;Expires=Mon, 09 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Mon, 09 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT
```

How can I fix this and keep using the fluent interface? Ideally I'd want a proper way to fix it, but since I don't really care about the cookies in my use case any solution that just allows me to stop displaying the warnings (besides redirecting stderr, cause I need that) is welcome.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The default HttpClient has difficulty understanding the latest RFC-compliant headers.

Instead of hiding the warning, just switch to a standard cookie spec like this (HttpClient 4.4+):

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
        .build())
    .build();
```

Comment: you nailed it. I am using springboot resttemplate and it required an extra step of setting httpclient of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory object which is then passed on to resttemplate

Comment: Here is report of this behaviour in HttpClient's jira with developer suggesting same thing: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1763

Comment: Is there a version of http client for which this is no longer a required setting?
Setting the cookie spec to 'standard' seems like a sensible default to me.

Comment: @MerijnVogel Apache HttpClient 5.1.3 is fully compliant with RFC 6265 by default and doesn't produce those kinds of warnings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764182/15647

Comment: As @comiventor said, my use case was also for Spring Boot. Adding the snippet here for easy reference :-
```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate =
            new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create()
         .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()).build()));
        return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to use `HttpClientBuilder` you can use the following sytax:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()).build();
```

Answer (score 18):

For the developers don't want to think on the object model, wrapping the HttpClient for a RestTemplate might be used as below ( as @comiventor mentioned above especially for Spring Boot Developers).

#### a Customizer for RestTemplate,

```java
public class RestTemplateStandardCookieCustomizer 
                         implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {

        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
            .build();

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(
          new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)
        );
    }
}
```

#### and using it with the RestTemplate Builder

```java
var restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.additionalCustomizers(
            new RestTemplateStandardCookieCustomizer()
        ).build();
```

Comment: Setting the customizer as a Component is enough for it to work. SpringBoot picks it up automatically, no need to use the restTemplate builder.

Answer (score 3):

Solved with:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies", "fatal");
```

Comment: Just to note that you may need different syntax depending on which logging library is in use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188118/cant-turn-off-htmlunit-logging-messages for alternatives.

Comment: For log4j2: Configurator.setLevel("org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies", Level.FATAL);

Comment: That's not "solving" anything, it's just hiding the error.

Comment: Quoting the question: "I don't really care about the cookies in my use case any solution that **just allows me to stop displaying the warnings** (besides redirecting stderr, cause I need that) is welcome."

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not directly related to the OP, but to help those looking for a solution to the problem. This is the first result on Google when searching `Invalid expires attribute`.

I am using [Resteasy](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/) as a transitive dependency of [Keycloak Admin REST Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client).

The problem is `resteasy-client` does not provide an easy way to configure the `Apache HttpClient` `HttpClient#RequestConfig#CookieSpec`. See the default `ClientHttpEngineBuilder` used by `resteasy-client` [ClientHttpEngineBuilder43](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/blob/1d0c21d73dd66c2bbb2080d3a3049dc3fab4f1ec/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ClientHttpEngineBuilder43.java#L196%3E).

To fix it, since the `ClientHttpEngineBuilder43#createEngine` method is `protected`, I have extended the class and specified the suggested `CookieSpecs.STANDARD`:

```java
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig.Builder;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngine;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngineBuilder43;

public class StandardCookieSpecClientHttpEngineBuilder extends ClientHttpEngineBuilder43 {

  @Override
  protected ClientHttpEngine createEngine(
      HttpClientConnectionManager cm,
      Builder rcBuilder,
      HttpHost defaultProxy,
      int responseBufferSize,
      HostnameVerifier verifier,
      SSLContext context) {
    // CookieSpecs.DEFAULT does not handle the latest RFC correctly
    // <https://stackoverflow.com/a/40697322/13688761>
    rcBuilder.setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD);
    return super.createEngine(cm, rcBuilder, defaultProxy, responseBufferSize, verifier, context);
  }
}
```

Then, the corresponding `ResteasyClient` and `Keycloak` are built as:

```java
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

  @Bean
  public Keycloak keycloak() {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
        // ... Some other configuration to the builder
        .resteasyClient(buildResteasyClient())
        .build();
  }

  private ResteasyClient buildResteasyClient() {
    ResteasyClientBuilder resteasyClientBuilder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
    // ... Some other configuration to the client builder
    return resteasyClientBuilder
        .httpEngine(
            new StandardCookieSpecClientHttpEngineBuilder()
                .resteasyClientBuilder(resteasyClientBuilder)
                .build())
        .build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache HttpClient 5.1.3 is fully compliant with [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) by default. Hence the following code doesn't produce warnings anymore:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;

//...

try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet)) {
        System.out.println(response.getCode() + " " + response.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```