# How to change the CookieSpec in Jersey Client?

Tags: cookies, jersey, httpclient, jersey-client, spring-jersey

I used Jersey Client in the project like this:

> clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
> clientConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
> client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

it actually use httpClient to do the job. but now I encountered the CookieSpec issue in this question: [Fixing HttpClient warning “Invalid expires attribute” using fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473478/fixing-httpclient-warning-invalid-expires-attribute-using-fluent-api). I need to change the CookieSpec but I cannot find where to change the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use the below solution：

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();
        clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.REQUEST_CONFIG, requestConfig);
```