# Invalid cookie header: Invalid 'expires' attribute

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, attributes, httpclient, paypal-ipn

I am using a standard RestTemplate of Spring boot 2.6.7, which corresponds to org.apache.httpcomponents -> httpclient -> 4.5.13.

Calling one public API causes some warnings to be present in the logs. The logger appears to be from httpclient from apache:
`org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies`
The warning is:

```
Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: ts=foo; Path=/; Domain=paypal.com; 
Expires=Sat, 21 Feb 2026 14:43:55 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure". 
Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 21 Feb 2026 14:43:55 GMT
```

I checked the source code of apache http client:

- The interceptor `org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies` influences the `org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies` one
- In the end it all falls down to using the `org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpec`
- which instantiates a `netscapeDraft` with `NetscapeDraftSpec.EXPIRES_PATTERN`, which is `EEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss z`
- so when the `DefaultCookieSpec` sees the attribute `expires` it goes and tries to parse it via the above mentioned pattern, which is legacy and failing (see below a screenshot from apache httpclient lib): [image]

I don't understand how come the default settings are not enough to have a perfectly conform date to be able to parsed properly.
The `PATTERN_RFC1123 = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"` would be working with `Sat, 21 Feb 2026 14:43:55 GMT`, but it is not used as default. In order to make it working I have to customize the cookie parsing explicitly, which appears ugly to me:

```
new RestTemplateBuilder()
.requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec("fixPaypalExpires").build())
                .setDefaultCookieSpecRegistry(CookieSpecRegistries.createDefaultBuilder()
                        .register("fixPaypalExpires",
                                new DefaultCookieSpecProvider(
                                        CompatibilityLevel.DEFAULT,
                                        PublicSuffixMatcherLoader.getDefault(),
                                        new String[]{"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"},
                                        false))
                        .build())
                .build()))
.build();
```

Or maybe I can use one of the pre-defined cookie spec providers, but still the default should work out of the box or? What do you think?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like acceptably answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473478/fixing-httpclient-warning-invalid-expires-attribute-using-fluent-api?r=SearchResults).

Even it is slightly about something else, it suggests a fairly acceptable workaround:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
    .build();
```